# log Mysql connect to remote rsyslog

Tags: mysql, rsyslog

I need to log the users that logs on mysql.

With the imfile module I read from the local mysql log

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/mysql/mysql.log"
    Tag="mysql-general"
    Severity="warning"
    Facility="local1")
```

I send it to the remote server (it's work).

But I need only to send the line with the word "Connect", and not all the messages.

I try:

```
if $syslogtag == 'mysql-general' and $msg contains 'Connect' then @*.*.*.*
```

it's still loggin anythings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found one possible solution.
We can add a ruleset:

```
ruleset(name="mysql_rule"){
    if $syslogtag == 'mysql-general' and $msg contains 'Connect' then @*.*.*.*
}
```

And change a little bit the input:

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/mysql/mysql.log"
    Tag="mysql-general"
    stateFile="statefile-mysql-general"
    Severity="warning"
    Facility="local1"
    ruleset="mysql_rule"
    reopenOnTruncate="on"
)
```